# Adding dashboard to the app.component

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing

I have login component and app component. When a user logs in, the following view is displayed,

[image]

Now user can click on the side nav menu button to get other details such as a dashboard. Like this,

[image]

When we click on dashboard, the dashboard component should display along with the side menu button and toolbar.

For side menu button and toolbar, I have a separate component called applayout model.

applayoutmodel.component.html

```
<div class="page">
    <div>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
    <div>
    <button class="menuButton" mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    <span class="companyName">Hello</span>
    </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
   </div>

    <mat-sidenav-container class="sideContainer" fullscreen  autosize style="top: 80px !important;">
      <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" opened="false" class="sideNav">
        <mat-nav-list>
         <button (click)="onDashboardClicked()">Dashboard</button>
          <nav class="menuItems">
            <a routerLink="/login">Login</a>
          </nav>
      </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
    </div>
```

applayoutmodel.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras, ActivatedRoute , Params } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../../serviceProviders/loginservice';
import { LoginComponent } from '../pages/login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applayoutmodel',
  templateUrl: './applayoutmodel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./applayoutmodel.component.scss']
})
export class ApplayoutmodelComponent implements OnInit {
  user_id: string = undefined;
  constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
  private loginservice: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onDashboardClicked() {
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showComponent">
<app-applayoutmodel></app-applayoutmodel>
</div>
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras, ActivatedRoute , Params} from '@angular/router';
import * as globals from '../app/pages/models/myGlobals';
import { LoginService } from '../serviceProviders/loginservice';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  showComponent = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private loginservice: LoginService ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.router.url);
      if ( this.router.url !== '/') {
        this.showComponent = true;
      }
      console.log(this.showComponent);
    }
}
```

and routing module as

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../app/pages/dashboard/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  {path: 'applayout', component: AppComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The output I am hoping for is

[image]

Comment: please can you give stackblitz link it will esay for me for making

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve1w8w , Please see once, getting some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post login, treat all other routes as a children to app component.
Therefore, your routes will look like this,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'applayout', component: AppComponent, children:[
     {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
  ]}
];
```

The app component will contain the top navbar. Once you navigate to dashboard, the dashboard component will be rendered inside the app component. Hence, the navbar will be present in the dashboard page as you have it in the image above.
The route to the dashboard will be `applayout/dashboard`.

Comment: it gave me an error as Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'applayout/dashboard'

Comment: Can you share your implementation? Would be good if you can create a plunker.

Comment: onDashboardClicked() {
    this.router.navigate(['applayout/dashboard']);
  }, I have changed like this.

Comment: You have missed out `/` in your code. It should be `this.router.navigate(['/applayout/dashboard'])`

Comment: Still, the toolbar and side nav are not getting displayed, created stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ve1w8w

Comment: The link you have posted doesn't work. They are having issues with your code. Here's an working example that might help you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ptajht

Comment: Thanks for the example, I am able to do it now, but there is a one more problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113853/component-not-getting-displayed-while-using-material-theme

Comment: Happy that it helped. Please, consider accepting my answer

Comment: Can you please help me with the question i have linked?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, you directly passed `opened="false"` to `mat-sidebar` which will eventually keep sidebar in closed state. Even though toggling `showComponent` will not change the sidebar state.

In this case I'd suggest you to add `showComponent` as in `@Input` binding to `AppLayoutModel` component, and used the same to toggle `opened` state of `mat-sidebar` component. Also change `showComponent` flag to `showSidebar`.

**app.component.html**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras, ActivatedRoute , Params } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from '../../serviceProviders/loginservice';
import { LoginComponent } from '../pages/login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-applayoutmodel',
  ...
})
export class ApplayoutmodelComponent implements OnInit {
  user_id: string = undefined;
  constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,
  private loginservice: LoginService) { }
  @Input() showSidebar: boolean;
  ....
}
```

**Html**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sideContainer" fullscreen  autosize style="top: 80px !important;">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="push" [opened]="showSidebar" class="sideNav">
    .....
  </mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```