# Unusual behaviour of mat-select in angular project

Tags: angular, angular-material

this question may be silly but I am not getting what else I can do.

I am including mat-select in my angular project as follows,

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Select Location" name="location">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let city of ['Sydney', 'Melbourne', 'Brisbane', 'Perth']" [value]="city">
              {{ city}}
              </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And I am getting the output as follows,

[image]

I am not getting What is wrong in my code, even when I click outside the select options, the options are not getting closed, they remain in list always once I click.

I have imported MatSelectModule in app.module.ts

Please help me to solve the Issue.

Here is the mat-comp.module.ts,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { BidiModule } from '@angular/cdk/bidi';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
import { PlatformModule } from '@angular/cdk/platform';
import { ObserversModule } from '@angular/cdk/observers';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';

import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatRippleModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatTooltipModule,

  MatStepperModule,
  MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS
} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    A11yModule,
    BidiModule,
    ObserversModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PlatformModule,
    PortalModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MatCompModule { }
```

and app.module.ts,

```
import { MatCompModule } from './mat-comp.module';
```

and also I have include **MatCompModule** in import array.

Comment: Have you imported mat form field module? mat option module

Comment: Every single component you use including nested components should be imported, otherwise it will be incomplete

Comment: I have included everything,,

Comment: Do you have @angular/animations and a theme?

Comment: I don't have a theme but I have installed @angular/animations from https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started this guide.

Answer (score 0):

you missed to import **[theme](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)** add `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` in your style.css

**[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmvrun)**

Comment: Please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113853/component-not-getting-displayed-while-using-material-theme/50114371?noredirect=1#comment87246419_50114371

Comment: The problem with including theme makes disappear of components,

Comment: That should not be the case you must have done something wrong I have provided you a working stackblitz  for the question you have asked.

Comment: provide a stackblitz or plunker.

Comment: I am bit confused here, when I does not apply material theme the sub components are getting displayed, but as soon as I apply theme, they are not getting displayed. I have explained the problem in question which is commented above. The same problem is appearing for mat-select when I include theme

Comment: well provide a stackblitz I will have a look at it

Comment: can you able to access this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c4apwl ??

Comment: You should probably **not** combine Bootstrap and Angular Material, consider using Angular Flex Layout.